# JAVA ANDROID:Reading Php Json values, Eclipse dont see the error but it doesnt work

Tags: java, php, android, json, eclipse

Reading Php Json values, Eclipse dont see the error but it doesnt work. Im becoming crazy because it must run, can you help me? 
When i execute it nothing happens.

This is the java activity code:

```
  package com.json.php;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class JSONExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://iatek.eu/sys/getsms.php");

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();                      
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("posts");

            /*Para hacer prueba accedo a un registro concreto en este caso el 3*/
               JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3);
                 String username = childJSONObject.getString("username");
                 String sms = childJSONObject.getString("sms");
                 String fcat = childJSONObject.getString("fcat");
                 textView.setText(""+sms+"--" + username);

            /* para hacer pruebas lo he comentado
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                 JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 String username = childJSONObject.getString("username");
                 String sms = childJSONObject.getString("sms");
                 String fcat = childJSONObject.getString("fcat");
                 textView.setText(""+sms+"--" + username);
            }*/



        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


       }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
         while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          answer.append(rLine);
           }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return answer;
       }
}
```

and here is the json code into iatek.eu/sys/getsms.php

```
{"posts":[{"cid":"11","username":"Livi","sms":"ag","fto":"","fcat":"cat"},{"cid":"10","username":"Sumone","sms":"","fto":"","fcat":""},{"cid":"9","username":"R2D2","sms":"dw","fto":"wd","fcat":"wd"},{"cid":"5","username":"Roy","sms":"sa","fto":"sa","fcat":"sa"},{"cid":"12","username":"Charles","sms":"ag","fto":"","fcat":"cat"},{"cid":"13","username":"Clarck","sms":"age","fto":"","fcat":"cat"}]}
```

can someone tell me where is the mistake? 
thanks

Comment: Hi, Why are using 'httpPost' ? your php seems to be reachable by a get request , Have you tried 'httpGet' instead ?

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: SORRY BUT I CANNOT POST AN ANSWER UNTILL 4 HOURS HAVE PASSEDO Thank you very much for your help yes Im trying that and things similar to that but they dnt run! , in this case, there are errors in the line

**protected void doInBackground(String... urls) {**
Multiple markers at this line - Line breakpoint:JSONExampleActivity [line: 26] - onCreate(Bundle) - The method execute(String) is undefined for the type JSONExampleActivity.GetSmsTask

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run network operation on the main thread.

Use [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

```
public class JSONExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new GetSmsTask().execute("http://iatek.eu/sys/getsms.php");
       }   

    private class GetSmsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
     protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
     JSONObject obj = null;
     try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                                                   .getContent()).toString();                      
            obj = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return obj;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj) {
      JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("posts");

       JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3);
         String username = childJSONObject.getString("username");
         String sms = childJSONObject.getString("sms");
         String fcat = childJSONObject.getString("fcat");
         textView.setText(""+sms+"--" + username);
     }
 }

}
```

EDIT:

I just ran the code myslef, and I got this

> 09-13 13:33:59.315: W/System.err(14200): org.json.JSONException: 
>   Unterminated object at character 7551 of {"posts":[{......

This means your JSON is invalid

http://pro.jsonlint.com/ paste your link there you will see the error.

To test that the code is working replace this

```
String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                     .getContent()).toString();
```

with this:

```
String jsonResult = "{\"posts\":" +
    "[{\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}," +
    " {\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}, " +
    "{\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}," +
    "{\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}]}";
```

Comment: Buf Im trying to use a asyntask, how should i do it or why happens that?

Comment: Please can someone send me a synctasc example with json?

Comment: @user2776893 this updaet should help, let me know

Comment: SORRY BUT I CANNOT POST AN ANSWER UNTILL 4 HOURS HAVE PASSEDO Thank you very much for your help yes Im trying that and things similar to that but they dnt run! , in this case, there are errors in the line

**protected void doInBackground(String... urls) {**
Multiple markers at this line - Line breakpoint:JSONExampleActivity [line: 26] - onCreate(Bundle) - The method execute(String) is undefined for the type JSONExampleActivity.GetSmsTask

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);

Comment: doInBackground is returning JSONObject  so change to `protected JSONObject  doInBackground`

Comment: ok i did that and this is ok, but now the line    ---->>>>>>>>>   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url[0]);, has troubles and the ---->>>  String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();, has troubles too ...

Comment: ok i turned url[0] into urls[0] and thats ok, now and, the last conflict is the next ->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

Comment: Sorry but im not able to run it, can you explain me please?

Comment: I forgot an s `urls[0]`

Comment: OK YOUR ACTIVITY WORKS , but I dont know where is the trouble in the json file , there have the same codification... I have test with that string, but how can I make an available php ? for this

Comment: THANKSSS A LO HAS A TROUBLEString jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity()
                      .getContent()).toString(); Multiple markers at this line HAS A TROUBLE
 - Line breakpoint:JSONExampleActivity$GetSmsTask [line: 48] - doInBackground(String...)
 - The method inputStreamToString(InputStream) is undefined for the type 
  JSONExampleActivity.GetSmsTask

Comment: Yes, how can i accept  it?  so unoe thing more, how can I repairthis? line?                            _--->    String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity() .getContent()).toString();

Comment: look under the zero(vote) there is a tick, simply check it. the problem is not in java anymore it is in php json, so post a  new question with this issue

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED!!!! ALL ITS PERFECT

HERE IS THE CODE

THANK YOU VERY MUCH meda

```
package com.json.php;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.json.php.R;

public class JSONExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new GetSmsTask().execute("http://YOURWEBSITE.eu/sys/getsms.php");
       }   

    private class GetSmsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
     protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
     JSONObject obj = null;
     try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
         /*   String jsonResult = "{\"posts\":" + //FOR TESTS
                    "[{\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}," +
                    " {\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}, " +
                    "{\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}," +
                    "{\"cid\":\"11\",\"username\":\"Livi\",\"sms\":\"ag\",\"fto\":\"\",\"fcat\":\"cat\"}]}";                     

            */
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString(); 
            obj = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return obj;

     }
     private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
         String rLine = "";
         StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

         try {
          while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
           answer.append(rLine);
            }
         }

         catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
         return answer;
        }

     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj) {
      JSONArray jsonArray;
    try {
        jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
          JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(3);
             String username = childJSONObject.getString("username");
             String sms = childJSONObject.getString("sms");
             String fcat = childJSONObject.getString("fcat");
             TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(""+sms+"--" + username);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     }
 }

}
```